# 2D FFT using 1D FFT with mpi

Tags: fortran, mpi, fftw

I'm trying to use a complex matrix with the dimensions (n x n) with the fftw_mpi subroutines (version 3.3.2): A 1D FFT (complex to complex) on all the rows and after a 1D FFT (complex to complex) for all columns. First I have made a serial code in Fortran, and everything is working properly, but when I'm trying the fftw subroutines with mpi the results are not as I expected. Is something wrong in how is created the plan for the 1D FFT transform? Below it is an example (only the first 1D FFT on the rows):

```
    !   get local data size and allocate (dimension reversal)

    alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_2d(M, L, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
                                                local_M, local_j_offset)

    cdata = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local)
    call c_f_pointer(cdata, ldata, [L,local_M])
    call c_f_pointer(cdata, data, [L,local_M])
    !   create MPI plan
    plan = fftw_mpi_plan_many_dft(1, L*local_M, local_M, FFTW_MPI_DEFAULT_BLOCK, &
    FFTW_MPI_DEFAULT_BLOCK, ldata, data, MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
    do j = 1, local_M
        do i = 1, L
     ldata(i,j)= my_function
    enddo
    enddo
    ! compute transform 
     call fftw_mpi_execute_dft(plan, ldata, data)
    call fftw_destroy_plan(plan)
    call fftw_free(cdata)
    call MPI_FINALIZE(mpi_err)
```

Comment: why is the result not as you expected?

Comment: I compared the results with a 1D FFT for the same matrix in Matlab and the results are different. Even more if I have a matrix with the dimensions(16x16)(in this case the local_M is 2) the code seems to applied the fft only on the first column allocated on each process. I suspect that the problem comes from the plan creation, but I can't track it or fixed. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try ploting both? generally I remember FFTW giving you the result in reverse order.

Comment: Was it ok with serial FFTW?

Comment: The problem is not that the values are mixed up but the calculation are wrong in fortran. I have made for the same function a 2D FFT with fftw_mpi which works ok, but I need to do this using 1D FFT on the column and after on the rows. First I made 1D FFT on the columns and I compared with the results from Matlab, for the same function, and the values are wrong.

Comment: The results are ok with serial FFTW. This is why I think it maybe something wrong with the plan creation or with allocation.